# British Pound Sign £ causing PG::CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding “UTF8”: 0xa3

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding, utf-8

When collecting information containing the British Pound Sign '£' from external sources such as my bank, via csv file, and posting to postgres using ActiveRecord, I get the error:

> PG::CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding “UTF8”: 0xa3

The 0xa3 is the hex code for a £ sign. The perceived wisdom is to clearly specify UTF-8 on the string whilst replacing invalid byte sequences..

```
string.encode('UTF-8', {:invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => '?'})
```

This stops the error, but is a lossy fix as the '£' is converted into a '?'

UTF-8 is able to handle the '£' sign, so what can be done to fix the invalid byte sequence and persist the '£' sign?

Comment: 0xa3 is the codepoint for the pound sign in microsuft's cp1252 (and iso8859-1). Your data is probably not coded as utf8. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Comment: You are right @wildplasser, the source file has Microsoft coding - an HTML file download with .xls extension. Ruby handled it as UTF-8 apart from the £ sign, which was not preceded by the correct character sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question thanks to Michael Fuhr who explained the [UTF-8 byte sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/B03E7678-25C9-4D9D-8805-42F59A88E515@mac.com) for the pound sign is 0xc2 0xa3. So, all you have to do is find each occurrence of 0xa3 (163) and place 0xc2 (194) in front of it...

```
array_bytes = string.bytes
new_pound_ptr = 0
# Look for £ sign 
pound_ptr = array_bytes.index(163)
while !pound_ptr.nil?
  pound_ptr+= new_pound_ptr # new_pound_ptr is set at end of block
  # The following statement finds incorrectly sequenced £ sign...
  if (pound_ptr == 0) || (array_bytes[pound_ptr-1] != 194)
    array_bytes.insert(pound_ptr,194)
      pound_ptr+= 1
    end
    new_pound_ptr = pound_ptr
    # Search remainder of array for pound sign
    pound_ptr = array_bytes[(new_pound_ptr+1)..-1].index(163)
  end
end
# Convert bytes to 8-bit unsigned char, and UTF-8
string = array_bytes.pack('C*').force_encoding('UTF-8') unless new_pound_ptr == 0
# Can now write string to model without out-of-sequence error..
hash["description"] = string
Model.create!(hash)
```

I've had so much help on this stackoverflow forum, I hope I have helped somebody else.